# Decorate private method of a super class in python

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a parent class `class Parent` and a sub-class `class Child(Parent)` in Python. All my logic is in the parent class except for some names present in Child class. Now, I want to profile the time taken in execution of a method which is actually present in Parent class without modifying the parent class (using it as a library). I have a decorator for profiling, is there a way to decorate private method of parent class from child class?

Comment: You could just override the method in the`Child` class and time it

Comment: I don't think parents' private methods are visible in Child.

Comment: Unlike other languages, nothing is really private in Python, everything is public. Prefixing the name with '_' is the sign that something is supposed to be private, but nothing stops you from using it.

Comment: The name has `__` prefixed in it, and it looks like it is not directly being overwritten in the child. I think there might be some other way to write the function in child.

Comment: If the name is prefixed with `__`, then to access it you call `Child()._Parent__method`. `Parent` is the parent class' name and `method` is the name of the method.